# Display a list of a user's Organic Groups

Tags: organic-groups

While searching, I've found a lot about how to programmatically add things to groups, but I'm wondering if there is a function that will take a parameter identifying the user and return a list of their groups.

Is there a function that takes user info and returns a list of groups for OG in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [og_get_groups_by_user()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/og_get_groups_by_user/7) for that.

> Get the group IDs of all the groups a user is an approved member of.

The API linked to above might be for OG 1.x, it's slightly different for OG 2.x.

```
 function og_get_groups_by_user($account = NULL, $group_type = NULL) {
 ...
```

For instance:

```
 global $user;
 $user_groups = og_get_groups_by_user($user, 'node');
```

The above example is not really great as `$account` defaults to current user and without `$group_type` you get all types of groups, not just node groups, but you get the general idea.